# Can I use SymEnumSourceFiles handle release program?

Tags: visual-c++, msdn

When I use `SymEnumSourceFiles` to enumerate all files loaded by a debug program, it is no problem. But when replaced with Release program, it cannot work, and the `GetLastError` returns `0`. If I want to enumerate all files loaded by a release program. what should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this problem. In Realease mode, we need to specify the path to the PDB. Add this line of code before `SymEnumSourceFiles` is OK.

```
SymSetSearchPathW(hProcess_, pdbPath);
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, you are saying `SymEnumSourceFiles` succeeds for Debug build programs, but fails for Release builds. If that's the case, your program just needs `.PDB` file along with.

You need to specify `/DEBUG` in Linker setting of the project. **No** it doesn't make Release build a Debug build - all optimizations remain, just that .PDB file is generated.

Comment: Thank you! But the Release build program also have .PDB file, and I do not specify /DEBUG in Linker setting of the project.